# C# Set node status in Tree hierarchy

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've a class with Tree hierarchy as below. I need to set Leaf node to status "InProgress". Then All ancestors needs to have change from NotStarted to InProgress. And if all leaf nodes were Complete, it immediate parent status need to be Complete. Is there a quick way to do it other than recursively iterating multiple times?

```
pubic class Node 
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public List<Node> Children { get; set; } = new List<Node>();
   public int NodeStatus {get; set;} // 1=>NotStarted (default); 2=> InProgress; 3=>Complete 
}
```

Comment: You can do it with an ordinary `while` loop, but then you'd have to create your own stack, the one that would have been used had you simply used recursion.

Answer (score 1):

One simple way can be that you make a different class for child notes and notify your parent class each time when its property is changed:

**Parent**

```
public class Node
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Node> Children { get; set; } = new List<Node>();
    private int _nodeStatus;
    // 1=>NotStarted (default); 2=> InProgress; 3=>Complete
    public virtual int NodeStatus 
    {
        get => _nodeStatus;
        set
        {
            _nodeStatus = value;
            // If started, then change all children property to 'In progress'
            if(value == 2)
                Children.ForEach(child => child.NodeStatus = 2);
        }
    } 
    private int CountCompleted { get; set; }

    public void NotifyChildChanged(int childStatus)
    {
        if (childStatus == 3)
        {
            CountCompleted++;

            if(CountCompleted == Children.Count)
                // Do your stuff
        }
        else
        {
            CountCompleted--;
        }
    }
}
```

**Child**

```
public class ChildNode : Node
{
    private int _nodeStatus;
    public override int NodeStatus 
    {
        get => _nodeStatus;
        set
        {
             _nodeStatus = value;
             NotifyChildChanged(value);
        }
    }
}
```

Basically, what you will have is a separate implementation of `NodeStatus` for **Parent** and **Child** classes and inside of their implementation you just put other needed methods like *changing childs' values* or *notifying parent about child's complete*. In the parent's case, however, you should be careful, because every time you change the parent it will change all children, so you might want to have also some kind of `private bool` which will be checking whether the *progress* has already been started or not.

P.S for simplicity, I used just methods, however, you might want to implement it through delegates and events.